# Why do I need source port on UDP

Tags: tcp, udp, port

When I use TCP I need destination port (to be able to "talk" to other process on the other host) and source port (because TCP is connection oriented so I'll send data back to source like ack, seq and more).
On the other side, UDP which is connectionless needs also source port.

Why is it? (I don't need to send back data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, two reasons.

First, receivers often need to reply and it is useful to provision a standard tool for that.

Secondly, you may have multiple interfaces (network cards) and using source address, you decide which of them must be used to emit the packet.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to but there's still the possibility to send a response back (that is very useful actually) however as stated in the RCF 768

> Source Port is an optional field, when meaningful, it indicates the port
> of the sending  process,  and may be assumed  to be the port  to which a
> reply should  be addressed  in the absence of any other information.  If
> not used, a value of zero is inserted.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the answers here. Apart from simply knowing what to reply to, the source port can belong to the [list of well-known port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports). These ports specify what kind of data is encapsulated in the UDP (or TCP!) packet.

For example, the source port 530 indicates that the packet contains a [Remote Procedure Call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), and 520 indicates a [Routing Information Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol) packet.